# At the command line, how can I 'arrow along' faster using words instead of chr's

Tags: keyboard, command-line, bash

I am at the command line and I have

`. /this/set/of/directory/this_command "parm1", "parm2", "parm3"`

When I 'up-arrow' to recall previous lines, how can I move *along* the line from "word to word". Ideally a directory separator slash ("/") will also count as word demarcation.

On other OS's I can use things like `ctrl-[left/right]arrow` or `alt-[left/right]` arrow to move "a word at a time" but I haven't yet found any keystroke combination on a mac that will let me do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general solution for the bash shell (Linux/Mac) : I set the Vi mode with

```
$ set -o vi
```

I have set it in the global /etc/bashrc file.

That way I can navigate with the usual vi keys within a command line after hitting the ESC key.

E.g. changing into Vi mode and then by pressing 'b' I can move back a word. And since the directory seperator counts as a word seperator it would work for your example.

Typing 'w' would move to the right again by a word each time. And so on

Answer (score 3):

In Terminal, you can use `opt-[left/right] arrow` to navigate word by word. Additionally, you can use `opt+click` to reposition the cursor.

Comment: what about iTerm?

Answer (score 0):

If you'd prefer not to switch to vi mode, you can check “Use option as meta key” under Preferences… > Settings > *any profile* > Keyboard. With that enabled you'll be able to hit <kbd>Opt+B</kbd> & <kbd>Opt+F</kbd> to move backward & forward a word at a time, along with a plethora of other emacs-style shortcuts.